# App Engine Adding custom domain verification failed despite main site ownership verified

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to veryfy a subdomain to configure a server side GTM container.

[image: Google cloud site verification]

The property is verified on the search console

[image: search consoile site verification]

However when I click refresh domain, I still get "Your domain hasn't been verified yet. Finish all the steps in Search Console  and then return to this page."

If I remove the property and start again, it is automatically verified as the main domain is also verified.

But there are no changes in the custom domain section. I cannot configure it to accept my A and AAAA records

EDIT

If I only validate the main domain, the A and AAAA records are not validated in Google App Engine DCustom Domains

[image: domains mapped]

What can I do here?

Comment: You only need to verify the root domain. Does the subdomain actually have NS records (delegated zone)?

Comment: @JohnHanley when I only validate the main domain, the A and AAAA records are not created correctly in the custom domain section. For another website I was able to verify the subdomain but don't know why it's nor working here

Comment: I have a similar issue, I hope you get a solution for this (I need it too)

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the refresh functionality, because it does not remove domains which one removes from the search console either.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issues with subdomain verification in Google App Engine after verifying the main domain in Google Search Console, follow these steps or refer to this link: [Map a subdomain to your app](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/custom-domain#map_a_subdomain_to_your_app)

> 1. Go to App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains in the Google Cloud Console.
> 2. Add a custom domain.
> 3. Select the verified domain or verify a new domain.
> 4. Complete the verification steps in Webmaster Central.
> 5. Remove the www. subdomain in the "Point your domain to [project-ID]" section and save the mappings.

Additionally, troubleshoot the issue using these steps:

1. Ensure the necessary DNS records are added for your subdomain. Double-check DNS records.
2. Allow up to 24 hours for DNS changes to propagate before re-verifying the subdomain.
3. Confirm that you are using the correct verification method.
4. Retry the verification process.

Additional Reference:

[Custom Domain Configuration](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/custom-domain)

[Set up server-side tagging with App Engine](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/app-engine-setup#configure_the_server_container_url)

[Host a Google App on your Domain](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6009957?hl=en)

Comment: this does not work, as you can see from my screenshot, I am the certified owner of the property on google search console but the domain appears as not verified in google cloud custom domains

Answer (score 0):

Using the gcloud CLI solved this exact issue for me:

`gcloud app domain-mappings create 'myvanitydomain.com' --certificate-management=AUTOMATIC`

The CLI utility responses with a CNAME record to give to your registrar.

Comment: Note that the certificate activation time was pretty long for me, counted in hours. I checked two days later and it was ok